# Increasing number of clients connections on Mosquitto broker

Tags: windows, client, mqtt, mosquitto, broker

I am working on a project where I want to use MQTT, some of my project requirements are around 25k clients connected and a message rate around 4000 messages/sec, after looking some open-source broker option I have been making some test whit mosquitto.

I am using a software called JMTER(it can simulate by threads the clients and messages that I need).

The machine where I am doing the test has 2 Intel® Xeon® Processors E5-2620 v3, it has 6 cores and 12 threads each one, and 9 GB ram,15M Cache, 2.40 GHz, my OS is windows server 2012 R2, so I have a good machine to host a broker.

To monitor my testing attempts I use MQTT explorer which is a plugging specially design to mosquitto.

I have been making some test trying 2k clients (1k publishing 1000 messages/second during 15 seconds, the message was “Hola1” and also 1k subscribers) these numbers where the highest ones that I could get, every time I tried to pass this number of clients mosquitto just died and I lost the connections.

I have been looking in web sites and some people say that mosquitto can handle up to 100k connections, some people say that you can configure your broker to support more connections but I haven’t figured out the way to configure my broker, is there any guide or documentation available to do this?

Comment: You've still not included any information about how you've configured mosquitto or the logs/error messages from when it crashes.

Comment: where can I see the logs/error?, currently I am using MQTT explorer to monitor the broker so I haven't use the CLI mode to interact whit moquitto

Comment: @KevinAle See `log_dest` and `log_type` in [mosquitto.conf](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html). When you say "mosquitto just died" do you mean it crashed (if so please describe in more detail) or that some connections were dropped?